# How to Force send 802.11 probe request manually for linux stations

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I would like to control the sending of 802.11 probe requests for a wireless linux station. By default the station will send probe requests periodically and I don't care about that. What I want specifically is to send a probe request when I ask it to.

Is there any way to do that using any of the known tools like nmcli, iw, iwconfig, wpa_supplicant etc.? or any other software tool out there that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask your wireless interface to do the AP scanning, then you basically send probe request. You can do it using `iw <wlan_interface> scan`.